# Prestashop 1.7 , sending email in proaccount module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

We are using proaccount , this module allow users to register as professionnal. This module send and email to staff when an you customer is register. I tried to edit the code but nothing happen , send mail method is not the same in prestashop doc

````
    {
        $context = Context::getContext();
        $id_lang = (int)$context->language->id;
        $iso = Language::getIsoById($id_lang);
        $id_shop = (int)$context->shop->id;
        $address_text = '';
        if ((int)Configuration::get('PROACCOUNT_REGISTER_WITH_ADDRESS')
            && (int)Configuration::get('PROACCOUNT_REGISTER_ADDRESS_PRO')) {
            $addresses = $customer->getAddresses($id_lang);
            $address = new Address($addresses[0]['id_address']);
            $address_text = AddressFormat::generateAddress($address);
        }
        if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/mails/'.$iso.'/pro_account.txt')
            && file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/mails/'.$iso.'/pro_account.html')) {
            $file_attachment = !empty($this->file_attachment['name']) ?
                $this->file_attachment : null;
            Mail::Send(
                $id_lang,
                'pro_account',
                $this->l('Professional account register'),
                array(
                    '{firstname}' => $customer->firstname,
                    '{lastname}' => $customer->lastname,
                    '{email}' => $customer->email,
                    '{company}' => $customer->company,
                    '{siret}' => $customer->siret,
                    '{address}' => $address_text,
                ),
                Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'),
                null,
                (string)Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL'),
                (string)Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
                $file_attachment,
                null,
                dirname(__FILE__).'/mails/',
                null,
                (int)$id_shop
            );
        }
    }```

Any help please ?
````

Comment: Prestashop mail method is documented here : 
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/mail/#using-the-mailsend-method
and it the same class used in your code.
I am not sure what did you edit but make sure that your Prestashop is properly configured for outgoing mail sending and the ""if"" conditions are met , especially that there is a proper e-mail template named "pro_account" in mails/xx folder of the module (where xx is the ISO language of the context language.

Comment: this is the original code. I tried to edit Configuration::get , nothing , i took a look on the classe , and tried to edit data , nothing too and my mails are working and templates too

Comment: If you're sure the issue doesn't come from a missing mail template, you should perform a debug of the "Send" method of Mail.php by checking what's happening at the $message variabile (PHP Swift Mail package is used for sending mails)

Comment: In the front controller , this controller extends AuthController and not ModuleFrontController like prestashop devdocs show. Do i have to create a new controller with extends ModuleFrontController like devdocs ?